# Meaning of each field in uWSGI stats

Tags: uwsgi

As [the official doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StatsServer.html) says, uWSGI allows us to get statistic data by JSON format, such as the following:

```
{
  "version":"2.0.12",
  "listen_queue":0,
  "listen_queue_errors":0,
  "signal_queue":0,
  "load":0,
  "pid":1,
  "uid":1000,
  "gid":0,
  "cwd":"/regent",
  "locks":[
    {
      "user 0":0
    },
    {
      "signal":0
    },
    {
      "filemon":0
    },
    {
      "timer":0
    },
    {
      "rbtimer":0
    },
    {
      "cron":0
    },
    {
      "rpc":0
    },
    {
      "snmp":0
    }
  ],
  "sockets":[
    {
      "name":"127.0.0.1:36577",
      "proto":"uwsgi",
      "queue":0,
      "max_queue":100,
      "shared":0,
      "can_offload":0
    }
  ],
  "workers":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "pid":9,
      "accepting":1,
      "requests":0,
      "delta_requests":0,
      "exceptions":0,
      "harakiri_count":0,
      "signals":0,
      "signal_queue":0,
      "status":"idle",
      "rss":0,
      "vsz":0,
      "running_time":0,
      "last_spawn":1457410597,
      "respawn_count":1,
      "tx":0,
      "avg_rt":0,
      "apps":[
        {
          "id":0,
          "modifier1":0,
          "mountpoint":"",
          "startup_time":0,
          "requests":0,
          "exceptions":0,
          "chdir":""
        }
      ],
      "cores":[
        {
          "id":0,
          "requests":0,
          "static_requests":0,
          "routed_requests":0,
          "offloaded_requests":0,
          "write_errors":0,
          "read_errors":0,
          "in_request":0,
          "vars":[

          ]
        },
        {
          "id":1,
          "requests":0,
          "static_requests":0,
          "routed_requests":0,
          "offloaded_requests":0,
          "write_errors":0,
          "read_errors":0,
          "in_request":0,
          "vars":[

          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "pid":10,
      "accepting":1,
      "requests":0,
      "delta_requests":0,
      "exceptions":0,
      "harakiri_count":0,
      "signals":0,
      "signal_queue":0,
      "status":"idle",
      "rss":0,
      "vsz":0,
      "running_time":0,
      "last_spawn":1457410597,
      "respawn_count":1,
      "tx":0,
      "avg_rt":0,
      "apps":[
        {
          "id":0,
          "modifier1":0,
          "mountpoint":"",
          "startup_time":0,
          "requests":0,
          "exceptions":0,
          "chdir":""
        }
      ],
      "cores":[
        {
          "id":0,
          "requests":0,
          "static_requests":0,
          "routed_requests":0,
          "offloaded_requests":0,
          "write_errors":0,
          "read_errors":0,
          "in_request":0,
          "vars":[

          ]
        },
        {
          "id":1,
          "requests":0,
          "static_requests":0,
          "routed_requests":0,
          "offloaded_requests":0,
          "write_errors":0,
          "read_errors":0,
          "in_request":0,
          "vars":[

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, there is no explanation about it.  What does each field mean?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163091/how-to-read-uwsgi-stats-output might be helpful